Battery size needed for a submersible pump
I bought a small solar fountain pump which does not work well on cloudy and monsoon days. So I want to hook this pump on to a battery which I am considering to recharge once in a month. The pump has no specifications written on it, I only know that the solar panel is 1.8 W. For reference the pump looks like this Amazon link, I am assuming it’s a 9 V pump. What size battery should I buy? And do I need any other electrical equipment?

Please measure the pump current consumption. Your battery will be large and expensive.

The amazon specs (if we can trust them...) are:

Solar panel power consumption: 7V 1.8W.
Pump power consumption: DC 4.5-10V.

Let's go with 7-8V 2W ; over a month that's 30 * 24h * 2W = 1440 Wh, so you'd need a battery of this capacity, or 2S LiIon 7.2V with 200Ah capacity, with BMS to avoid overdischarge.
A much cheaper option would be to fit a larger solar panel, or a power supply from mains.

If I choose solar panel, how big should it be ? It rains for almost 8 months here so most days are cloudy.

On a cloudy day you'll get about 10% of nominal power so a solar panel with 20W
and 6-8V should work. It will be much cheaper than batteries. You can also get panels of the right voltage but less watts, and wire them in parallel. Whatever's cheaper. Note cheap solar panel specs are often fake. For 20W it should be at least 0.1 square meters (30x30 cm).

Thanks, I will go with solar as suggested
